# Where to place code to check authentication id better in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have an application which authenticates users against some remote backend. This backend takes `login` and `password` and returns `session id` which then should be used as access token in that backend API.

I'd like to check if session is alive (and touch it so it would not expire in the remote system) in every user request. I implemented method `IUserIdentity::authenticate` which acquires session id from backend, but cannot find the better place where to put the code which touches/validates session in the remote system in every user request. Seems neither `UserIdentity` nor `WebUser` has no hooks for this purpose.

What is the right place to put this code? Some `beforeAction` in controller?

Comment: Yo can use [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) as in default access control

Answer (score -2):

Use the UserIdentity.php in components

UserIdentity

```
public function authenticate()
{   //Replace the code wit your stuff }
```

Comment: "I implemented method IUserIdentity::authenticate which acquires session id from backend, but cannot find the better place where to put the code which touches/validates session in the remote system in every user request." - quote from question.